# Summing characters in lines from a text file?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I have a text file like this:

```
This is just
an example of
a textfile
```

and would like to find the sum of all words that don't contain an "e". This sum is to be printed for every line, and should be the total sum of words in that line.

Currently I have this:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
   count = 0
   for line in f:
   words = line.split()
   for word in words:
      if "e" not in word:
         for char in word:
            count += 1
         print(count)
```

and the output I get is:

```
4
6
10
12
14
15
```

when it should be:

```
10
4
1
```

Comment: It looks like the request is that they sum all characters in words which don't contain an e

Comment: It looks like you aren't resetting the count variable, so the result is always strictly increasing (and thus you aren't getting counts per line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `len` builtin to get the length of a string. The reason you're getting larger numbers than you expect is that you're not resetting the `count` variable for each line, and also you're printing after every word, not each line.

```
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        count = 0
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if "e" not in word: 
               count += len(word)
        print(count)
```

You can write this more compactly as

```
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(sum(len(word) for word in line.split() if 'e' not in word))
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise that to reset the count variable I needed to place it inside the for loop.